# Struts 2 - Generated form action

Tags: forms, jsp, struts2

I create a form with Struts 2, using the following code :

```
<s:form id="form" onSubmit="getParameters();">
```

I don't understand why the generated is the following one :

```
<form id="form" name="form" action="/Projet/ListAction.action" method="post" onSubmit="return getParameters();">
```

Here is my struts.xml

```
 <action name="ListBrochures" class="fr.web.actions.ListAction" method="execute">
    <result name="success">listAction.jsp</result>
  </action>
```

Why  i have an action called ListAction.action. My aim is not to submit the form but to send a Ajax request. So as this action is called before my Ajax call, this bring trouble in my project.
I just want that Struts does not generate the action in my form. I did not specify any action.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: i believe it is getting it from current one.set `theme=simple` like `<s:form theme=simple ...>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation (parameter `action`), if you don't set any action in your `<s:form>` tag, the action that struts2 take will be the current action.

- [Form tag](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/docs/form.html) documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I read documentation but i don't understand very well what means current action. Could you give me an example please.

Comment: I guess it will be the action that render the jsp in which the form is. Probably you have in your `struts.xml` something like `<action name="ListAction"><result>form-jsp.jsp</result>...`

Comment: It is possible to not have an action attribute ? When i click on submit my aim is to send Ajax request. But now i send first first a request to action url and next to my ajax url.

Comment: I believe that if you `return false` in your submit handler, you will prevent the default action in the form. Also you can put a `<button>` inside the form (not a `submit` tag) with a `click` event and then call ajax inside the `onclick` handler.

Comment: @user1613902 I put you a comment (that's because I believe that if I don't put your name, you won't get the notification).

Comment: Oh Yes ! You're right Pigueiras ! Why i did not think to this solution. I am ashamed. Thank guy, you are great guy !